# How do I use parameters with ksoap2?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have created a web service to test passing parameters via ksoap2.  I thought it seemed like a pretty simple process, but I'm apparently missing something simple.  The web service does nothing more than return the integer that is passed to it.  When I execute the code below it returns the number 0 instead of 1.

```
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/TestParams";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "TestParams";
private static String URL = "http://services.lockrem.com/WebService.asmx?WSDL";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("RoundId", 1);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Note: I have tested this using a .net web page and it returns the number 1 as expected.  The web service is not the issue here.

Here is the web service.

```
    [WebMethod]
public int TestParams(int RoundId)
{
    return RoundId;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this. I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Whenever I try to talk to a .NET webservice using kSoap2, I usually end up doing a lot of *fiddling*. And I mean that literally: I setup a windows machine with [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and use that as a proxy for both the failing request and a working reference request, so I can actually *see what's going wrong*. I strongly advise doing something similar as soon as you try to do something non-trivial.

That said, in your case, it might be enough to do

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Unfortunately, that did not make any difference.  I will download Fiddler2 and see how that can help me.

Comment: Fiddler shows a lot of interactions, but is not showing any reference to the web services I am calling from the android emulator.  Even the android activity that works is not showing up on fiddler.

Comment: I still need some assistance.  While I appreciate the current help, this suggestion did not result in any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the WSDL at the end

```
private static String URL = "http://services.lockrem.com/WebService.asmx";
```

In addition try using this to get the response:

```
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
```

instead of `SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;`

**EDITED**

This works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "TestParams";
private static String URL = "http://services.lockrem.com/WebService.asmx";
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("RoundId", 1);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    try {
        transport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
        tv.setText(response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I did try this, but still am getting the same result (0 instead of 1).  This is a public web service.  If anyone can make it produce a 1 I would greatly appreciate knowing how it is done.